# Have US anti-ballistic-missile capabilities been used and were they effective in countering the recent Iranian missile strike on US bases in Iraq?

Tags: united-states, military, iran, iraq

This is breaking news, so it may not be answerable right away but probably will be in a reasonably short term...

Iran [has launched](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-51028954) (from its own territory) ballistic missile strikes against US bases in Iraq.

> Two Iraqi bases housing US and coalition troops were targeted - one at Al Asad and one in Irbil at about 2:00am local time (10.30pm GMT), just hours after the burial of Soleimani. [...]
>
> This is the most direct assault by Iran on the US since the seizing of the US embassy in Tehran in 1979.
>
> Iran's Revolutionary Guards said the attack was in retaliation for the death of Soleimani on Friday - killed in a missile strike outside Baghdad airport on the orders of President Trump.

Given that the US has substantial anti-ballistic missile capabilities, have these been used to counter the strike and have they been effective in doing so?

CNN now [reports](https://edition.cnn.com/middleeast/live-news/us-iran-soleimani-tensions-intl-01-07-20/h_8b59b20f18c0a6efcea7267068bdcbd2) that there were no casualties in these Iranian attacks.

> A Dubai-based western private security source with staff at the al-Asad and Erbil military bases told CNN there were “no casualties” in Wednesday's Iranian missile attack.
>
> “To be honest, rocket attacks are nothing new to us. It is business as usual,” the source told CNN.

It's also possible (as noted in a comment below) that no anti-ballistic defenses existed at these bases, which is why they may have been targeted in this manner. But from the CNN source, it seems there might have been other procedures in place to minimize casualties in case of such an attack. (I guess the US could at least detect the launches and send personnel to bunkers, if they don't live/sleep there permanently.) Although these procedures might not be disclosed, it would be interesting to know, to the extent that is possible with public information, why there were no casualties. (Scud type missiles not being particularly accurate, etc.)

Comment: Maybe USA dont want to counter the missile strike :)

Comment: I can't find any source that says Al Asad is defended by Patriot or any other kind of ABM system, as opposed to a CIWS. Not sure if that's an answer ("no, those capabilities are not deployed there") or if the premise of the question needs changing.

Comment: @DanScally: It is an answer. It also means that Iran probably selected those targets because they lacked ABM.

Comment: @Fizz, Iran selected this targets because the drones involved in General Soleimani assassination was belong to this bases. Also Trump said that they has spent $7 Trillion Dollars on this bases.

Comment: ..and I don't know they defended by Patriot or any other kind of ABM system. but you can see that Patriot system is not reliable always just by seeing the recent attack of Yemenis force to Saudi Arabia oil refinery where equipped by Patriot system.

Comment: [A source within the Kurdistan Regional Government confirmed to ABC News that three missiles had been fired at Erbil International Airport and the adjoining U.S. military base but that two of the missiles were shot down by anti-missile batteries and the third fell behind the airport and did not detonate.](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/abcnews.go.com/amp/International/iran-missile-strikes-us-military-facilities-iraq-analysis/story%3fid=68132626)

Comment: these would not be *ballistic* missiles, in the sense generally understood when referring to ICBMs and the like.  there a number of tactical antimissile systems around that could have defended these bases, but they are in a different class than say the ones meant to intercept a NK launch.

Comment: @C.F.G: weren't drones used in those attacks instead of missles?

Comment: @dandavis: because drones against drones do not afford what Iranian people want even this attack is not enough and afford they revenge!! Note That Trump threatens to strike 52 Iranian targets, But Now Iranians after **5** days, destroyed **2** bases of US in the region. Isn't that awesome reply?!

Comment: @Fizz: Note that Almost no media speaks about inability of Patriot system, because their beautiful facilities are sold so good and the customers pays for nothing.

Comment: Is this question about politics? It's more about military strategy or maybe investigative journalism, but otherwise offtopic here I would say.

Comment: "There are only four systems in the world that can intercept ICBMs. Besides them, some smaller systems exist (tactical ABMs) that generally cannot intercept intercontinental strategic missiles, even if within range—an incoming ICBM simply moves too fast for these systems." – [Anti-ballistic missile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-ballistic_missile#Current_counter-ICBM_systems)

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: they are definitely TBM (tactical ballistic missiles) per the usual terminology https://www.defensenews.com/digital-show-dailies/dubai-air-show/2017/11/14/raytheon-saudi-based-patriots-intercepted-over-100-tbms-since-2015/

Comment: @C.F.G. No the US didn't spend $7 trillion on Iraqi drone bases, or all of Iraq. Trump [had previously claimed in 2018 the US had spent $7 trillion total on *all* Middle East wars](https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2018/may/01/donald-trump/donald-trump-and-7-trillion-dollar-cost-war/), which politifact rated as 'Half True', since it included future spending estimates for the next 30 years.

Comment: @Fizz perhaps.  but ABM is usually thought to refer to anti-ICBM tech, like the THAADS or enhanced Aegis and would have been covered by the defunct US-Russia ABM treaty.  Stuff here wouldn't.  Point is that something typically used for point-defense of a base like this - say Iron Dome or Patriot - would not necessarily have anything to do with ABM capabilities, as that term is generally understood.  If they had been used and worked, that shouldn't be conflated with success likelihood of ICBM defenses - which is poor at the moment.  Yes, yes, nitpick territory, well aware of.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It doesn’t seem so. Citing an unnamed US official, the LA Times reports that no attempt was made to intercept the missiles and those that did not fail during flight did hit the base. The lack of casualties was due to early warning radar which allowed base personnel to take cover:

> Iran launched 15 missiles, of which 11 hit their targets and four failed in flight, according to a U.S. defense official, who said there were no reports of U.S. casualties in the attack.
>
> Ten of the missiles hit the sprawling Asad Air Base in Iraq’s western Anbar province. **U.S. radar was able to track the missiles in flight and, as a result, personnel at the base were able to take cover. The U.S. made no effort to intercept the missiles, the official said.**
>
> One missile hit the Combined Joint Operations Center in Irbil, where the U.S. trains Iraqi Kurdish fighters and also runs a large air operations control center covering northern Iraq and parts of Syria.
>
> [Iran launched 15 missiles. 11 hit targets, according to a U.S. defense official - LA Times](https://www.latimes.com/world-nation/liveblog/live-updates-iran-missile-strike-us-base#iran-launched-15-missiles-11-hit-targets-according-to-a-u-s-defense-official)

Comment: Another explanation for the lack of casualties has been floated: Iran intentionally aiming for near misses, and notifying Iraq immediately beforehand (who most likely passed the message on to the US, even though this article doesn't explicitly say so): https://www.cnn.com/2020/01/08/politics/trump-iran-retaliation-missile-attacks/index.html

Comment: @llama, that might be possible for the attack on Asad airbase, which reportedly used Fateh-110 missiles with three-meter accuracy, but the attack on Irbil was reported to have used the Qiam 1 missile, which has a 50% chance of missing the target by more than 500 meters.

Comment: @Mark now that I actually look at the LA times link, the satellite imagery shows them hitting at least some structures, which seems like an odd choice if you're avoiding casualties

Comment: @llama: according to that CNN piece, the Iranians did not communicate to Iraq what they intended to strike exactly only that telling them that the strike would be "limited to the whereabouts of the US military in Iraq, without giving the exact location." I'm not sure that level of warning had more practical value than early warning radar...

Comment: @Fizz true, but I think "we're going to launch missiles at American bases within [short timeframe]" would probably be promptly relayed as a message for all American personnel to drop what they're doing and get to cover until there's an all-clear issued. It has the slight advantage of annoying everyone by wasting their time, while still giving almost as much casualty reduction potential as a specific message would.

Comment: @llama then Iran would be relying on Irak's chain of command working like a clockwork so that the message gets passed. But any failure (some general is unavailable and his subordinates do not have the initiative to bypass him, or the message is not believed) and then the message is not communicated and you have unintendently escalated the conflict. It seems like a big gamble to rely on this if you do not actually want casualties.

Comment: There have been comments (on CNN I think) that Iran specifically tried to avoid human casualties. Apparently they wanted to show force by retaliating but didn't want to go so far as causing massive escalation on US side.

Comment: @Mark thanks for that clarification!  The "Iran avoided casualties" line has gained a lot of traction in recent days.  Interesting to hear that would be rather difficult given the technology involved :)

Comment: Likely they want to avoid casualities but look strong to their own pop, claim the attack as theirs, then do the real damage with cyber attack or something similar to what happened to the saudi oil refinery, which they then can deny.

Comment: @StianYttervik Or to simply not do real damage at all because they don't want to be the next U.S. drone or missile target. Most likely a way to look like they're being strong and "teaching the U.S. a lesson," while trying as hard as possible to not actually provoke any retaliation from the U.S. Although, now they may be provoking retaliation from Canada and Ukraine... and perhaps their own citizens.

Comment: @reirab I doubt that, but of course it may be you are right. I assume they need to make assassinations of top leaders hurt so much it isn't worth it. I mean, it is in the personal interest of every political and military leader in Iran to poke back with a sharp blade - as long as they can deny it officially.

Comment: @StianYttervik If they were trying to make it "hurt," they failed miserably. The only casualties were when they themselves then proceeded to shoot down an airliner filled with mostly their own citizens. Much more likely, it was a posturing move designed to look 'strong' for their own people while trying not to provoke an actual U.S. response. That might have worked, if they hadn't then shot down the airliner. That's a PR disaster for the Iranian government, since one of their biggest anti-U.S. talking points has been the Iran Air shootdown for the last 30+ years, including a few days ago.

Comment: @StianYttervik It was just Monday when the President of Iran tweeted about how people should "should remember the number 290," in reference to the Iran Air flight that was mistakenly shot down in 1988. Talk about a tweet that didn't age well for his regime.

Comment: @reirab be that as it may, it is not a survival strategy for a political or military leader to do nothing. Clearly. If the US can kill with impunity a leader of Iran, then they have no safety anywhere. It is in their best interest to make it an unappealing choice in the future. They are backed into a corner and the only way forward is through. That is why it wasn't a good choice to kill the man. Do not engage your enemy on killing ground (Sun Tzu) that  is - you should only flight if the enemy has opportunity to flee the battlefield.

Comment: @StianYttervik The whole point of killing him was to make the point that people plotting attacks against the U.S. have no safety anywhere... Given their response, it appears that the point was made and both sides, at least for now, appear to be backing down from further escalation.

Comment: @reirab Yep, and it was still a bad choice to do it like that. Better to do it in response to an actual wrongdoing, or some discreet spec ops thing. But no, CiC wanted fire and brimstone, and it'll likely produce some fallout. Maybe luck strikes, that the airplane they shot down made them stumble in their step, but I doubt that any nations leaders are willing to just let fly getting assassinated in the line of duty. It must be a bad deal for the or else they become vulnerable. There is a reason that he hasn't been taken out before.

Answer (score 26):

There were none located in those places.

Those paragraphs from [Foxnews](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/trump-to-make-statement-on-iranian-missile-strikes-assures-nation-all-is-well) explain: (emphasis mine)

> U.S. defense officials told Fox News the U.S. military did not attempt to shoot down the ballistic missiles fired from Iran because there were no American military assets in place to intercept them. The Patriot and Avenger anti-missile defense systems are deployed to other locations in the Middle East, but not to the two Iraqi bases targeted by Iran. Officials say the American assets are in high demand and short supply around the world.
>
> “For the past few years, our focus was defeating ISIS and keeping a light footprint in Iraq. **We did not need air defense systems against ISIS**,” one official said, explaining why there were no U.S. missile defense systems in place at the Iraqi bases.

Comment: Just to confirm new york times likewise states that this particular base did not have anti missle defenses as well: https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/08/us/politics/trump-iran-suleimani.html

Comment: Another way of interpreting that last paragraph is that they were prepared the way they needed to be to fight the enemy they knew they had (ISIS). They were not prepared for civilian leadership to suddenly make them a target of a state actor with state resources (like medium-range missiles).

Comment: Iran may have issued a hint of an imminent missile strike on the two U.S bases just to avoid any deaths that may lead to a full blown war.